# How to allow external script to load in Chrome Extension popup.html via Content Security Policy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

Chrome is giving me the following error:

`Refused to load the script 'http://domain.com/myexternalscript.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"`

Currently, in my manifest my Content Security Policy is as follows:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

How do I alter my security policy so that it can allow the script to run?

Comment: On a normal page, you could use `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://domain.com;`, but [extensions only allow external scripts over HTTPS](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script), so you'll need to use `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://domain.com;` and serve your script over HTTPS.

Comment: ok, yes it gave me an error when i tried to add the url, and i just gathered that it needs to be https url. I don't have SSL on my web server. Any way to get https easily?

Comment: Also, can I do this for multiple URLs (future reference)?

Comment: I've actually been wanting an SSL certificate for a long time. Today I actually successfully installed one! For free!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a normal page, you could use

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' domain.com; ...
```

but extensions only allow external scripts over HTTPS. You'll need to use

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://domain.com;
```

and serve your script over HTTPS.

You must whitelist each external domain you want to use. You can use wildcards to match any subdomain: `https://*.domain.com`.

See Google's extension documentation on [relaxing the default CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script) for more information. See also MDN's page [Using Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy).

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question exactly.

Comment: Even after adding this I still get the error and it refuses to load the script.

Comment: NEVERMIND I forgot to add the `s` for _http **s** ://domain.com/myexternalscript.js_ into `popup.html`. IT WORKS! THANK YOU :) :)